# Am I targeting the wrong class? Bootstrap scrollspy not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

The nav links work, but when scrolling down the page, it does not highlight the current link according to the position.
It doesn't work when I comment out my custom.css so I can't figure out what's happening. I would like the scroll spy to highlight the nav item when I am scrolling over the area, if possible with #ff3b3f. Any pointers would be great :)

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>GSD Lexi - German Shepherd Dog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">GSD Lexi</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#tricks">Tricks</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#equipment">Equipment</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>   
    <!-- /navbar -->

    <!-- jumbotron -->
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container text-sm-center pt-5">
        <h1 class="display-2">Lexi the GSD</h1>
        <p class="lead">A one page website for a German Shepherd Dog.</p>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gsdlexi/" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Follow on Instagram!</button></a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /jumbotron -->   
    <div class="container pt-4">
      <!-- about -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <h1 id="about" class="my-5 display-4">About</h1>
          <img src="img/lexi-about.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded mb-4" alt="Responsive image">
          <p>Lexi is a purebred German Shepherd Dog living in Brisbane, Queensland. She loves a good game of fetch and walks of all sorts.</p>
          <p>Her favourite foods are cheese, chicken necks, and a BIG raw bone! Although she would probably eat anything in her bowl.</p>
          <p>She's not really fond of cats and is afraid of vacuums and water hoses.</p>
          <p>You can check out all the tricks Lexi can perform below or follow her daily routines on <a href="#">Instagram</a></p>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /about -->
      <!-- tricks -->
      <div class="tricks">
        <h1 id="tricks" class="my-5 text-center display-4">Tricks</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/sit.jpg" alt="Sit photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Sit</h5>
              </div>
            </div>            
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/down.jpg" alt="Down photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Down</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/shake.jpg" alt="Shake photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Shake</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/roll-over.jpg" alt="Roll over photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Roll Over</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/spin.jpg" alt="Spin photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Spin</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/hands-up.jpg" alt="Hands up photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Hands Up</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/weave.jpg" alt="Weaving photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Weave</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/play-dead.jpg" alt="Playing dead photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Play Dead</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="img/place.jpg" alt="Place photo">
              <div class="card-body mb-2">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Place</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>                
      </div><!-- /tricks -->

      <!-- equipment -->
      <h1 id="equipment" class="my-5 display-4 text-center">Equipment</h1>
      <p class="text-center mb-5">These are the equipment Lexi uses on a day to day basis.</p>
      <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Brand</th>
            <th scope="col">Website</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Collar</td>
            <td>Ezy Dog</td>
            <td><a href="https://ezydog.com.au/">www.ezydog.com.au</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Lead</td>
            <td>Ezy Dog</td>
            <td><a href="https://ezydog.com.au/">www.ezydog.com.au</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Fetch Balls</td>
            <td>Chuck It!</td>
            <td><a href="http://chuckit-toys.co.uk/">www.chuckit-toys.co.uk</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">4</th>
            <td>Grooming Brush</td>
            <td>FURminator</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.furminator.com/">www.furminator.com</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>      
      <!-- /euipment -->

      <!-- callout button -->
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gsdlexi/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-block mx-auto my-5">Lexi on Instagram!</button></a>

      <hr>
      <p class="text-center small">Copyright &copy; GSD Lexi 2019</p>
    </div><!-- /.container -->    

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Custom CSS:

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ABeeZee|Amatic+SC:700');

body {
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-image: url('../img/ft-bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', bold;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#equipment,
#tricks, 
#about {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', bold;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FF3b3F;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #000;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #FF3b3F;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #CAEBF2;
    border-color: #CAEBF2;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #FF3b3F;
    border-color: #FF3b3F;
}
```

Playground - https://codepen.io/brianquan/pen/oJKdWx

Comment: Please put the code you wrote on Stackoverflow and not on external pages only (You can of course provide a link to a webpage which offers some functionality, e.g. a playground), but your code should also appear on SO.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will make changes